# The last time we [have seen] [saw] [had seen] it, it was a gate

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

1. The last time **we've seen** it, it **was** a gate.
2. The last time we **saw** it, it **was** a gate.
3. The last time **we'd seen** it, it **was** a gate.

I'm not certain about the aforementioned sentences, namely, which is/are correct and meaningful constructions.

Further confusion is brought by these constructions from one authoritative textbook:

> This **is** the first/only/best/worst time I **have heard** her sing.
>
> This **was** the third time I **had been** in love that year.

So what is the right way of using tenses in the given context?

Comment: Based on the link below, the actual sentence was, "The last time we've seen **anything like it**, it was a gate", which I think changes things a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the sentence is: "The last time we've seen anything like it, it was a gate".

As a native Australian English speaker, it sounds basically fine, though when written down it looks slightly incorrect, and probably isn't how I would express that.

The confusion may arise from these similar expressions:

- This is the first time we've seen it.
- We've seen it for the last time.
- We haven't seen anything like it.

Answer (score 3):

(1) doesn't make sense. (2) would be the normal way to say it (assuming that, in a place where you remember there being a gate, there is now a fence or something else).
(3) would only be used in a story told in the past tense (the speaker remembers having seen a gate at an earlier time).

*This was the third time I had been in love that year* is also a sentence from a past-tense narrative.

*This is the first/only time I have heard her sing* is correct. I wouldn't use *best* or *worst* in that context.

Comment: Funnily enough I heard a native speaker say (1) in a TV-show, this is why I've created my question (I got confused). Here's what the native speaker said: "*No idea. All I know is that something's causing this disturbance, and the last time **we've seen** anything like it, it was a gate. And I hope it is because then we'd have a way to Vecna.*"

Comment: Here's the moment: https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=365256335701930

Comment: I'm not familiar with the context of the show, but he seems to mean "The last time we saw anything like this disturbance, it was being caused by a gate". I don't know why he uses the perfect tense; I wouldn't, but it may be normal for his colloquial idiom.

Comment: The cited usage is probably just the actor "mis-speaking". Imho the construction is syntactically invalid, and the scriptwriter probably *wouldn't* have set it down like that in the first place. But it's a fairly easy mistake to make. I certainly wouldn't dignify the usage as a "dialectal" form - it's just a trivial slip of the tongue. No biggie. (Perhaps the actor is distracted by thinking of *We **haven't** seen anything like this **since** that "last time"*, which is very close to the meaning he's *supposed* to be expressing.)